# Nginx: How to map the internal Ip addresses and proxy using ngrok without redirecting

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, proxypass

I have two device which can be accessed only using internal network.

To access it externally i have installed nginx in raspberry device and added a redirect within nginx like

```
location /device1
{
  return 301 http://192.168.0.1:80
}
```

Similarly device2 i have added and now i have used ngrok and exposed the localhost:80 externally.

**Problem**:
If i am in the same network of device1 and device2 i am able to connect it.

If i change my network i am able to access the nginx default page.

***Now If i append device1 it says page not found.***

**Solution Required:**

*How do i connect device1 and device2 from different network.?*

Why is this required say for example i am running a application in amazon i want to connect to my internal device ip and access the data.

Comment: `192.168.0.0/16` is a private IP address range. Only a device in the same network can access it. The `return` directive sends a HTTP redirect, i.e. asks the browser to retrieve the page. **nginx** should retrieve the page itself (`location /device1/ { proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1/; }`).

Comment: Thank you it worked